# Busca avançada em Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-blade

Estou iniciando em `Laravel 5` e como aprendizado estou criando um simples cadastro de funcionário. O que preciso é recuperar do banco um relacionamento de funcionários com exames baseado em condições (filtros) de busca.

No exemplo abaixo, utilizei o `When` para incluir a condição `Where` caso o filtro funcionário seja preenchido.

```
$employees = Employee_Exam::join('employees', 'employees.id', '=', 'employee_exams.employee_id')
                        ->distinct()
                        ->when($id_employee, function ($query) use ($id_employee) {
                            return $query->where('employees.id', $id_employee);
                        })
                        ->orderBy('employees.nome', 'asc')
                        ->get(['employees.id','employees.nome', 'employees.identidade', 'employees.company_id']);
```

Isso funciona perfeitamente. Em outro teste desejo buscar os exames de funcionários cujo vencimento esteja entre as datas de início e fim definidas através do filtro de pesquisa.

Minha dúvida é em como utilizar a mesma ideia do `When` para mais de uma condição no `Where`. Tentei o código abaixo mas sem sucesso.

```
$exames = Employee_Exam::join('employees', 'employees.id', '=', 'employee_exams.employee_id')
                        ->join('exams', 'exams.id', '=', 'employee_exams.exam_id')
                        ->when($data_inicio, $data_final, function ($query) use ($data_inicio, $data_final) {
                            return $query->whereBetween('next_exam',[$data_inicio , $data_final]);
                        })
                        ->orderBy('employee_exams.next_exam', 'asc')
                        ->get(['employee_exams.*','employees.id', 'employees.identidade', 'exams.exame']);
```

Comment: A SQL Builder que você fez não trouxe os resultados ou deu erro?

Comment: Erro: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233: Porém seu eu alterar a Query para ->whereBetween('next_exam',[$data_inicio , $data_final]), retirando a condição When tudo funciona normalmente.

Comment: `Erro: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233` o que tem nessa linha?:

Comment: O erro está ao passar duas variáveis no `when()`, somente aceita uma. Não tenho como testar, por isso não poste resposta, mas veja se funciona se separar as coisas, algo assim: `->when($data_inicio, function ($query) use ($data_inicio) {
                            return $query->where('next_exam', '>=' , $data_inicio );
                        })
                        ->when($data_final, function ($query) use ($data_final) {
                            return $query->where('next_exam', '<=' , $data_final );
                        })`

Comment: Show de bola @Evert. Funciona perfeitamente, inclusive com mais parametros. Pode responder a pergunta por favor que marcarei como resposta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está na quantidade de argumento enviado na cláusula `when()`, que atualmente aceita somente um.

Uma sugestão seria quebrar em duas, conforme segue:

```
$exames = Employee_Exam::join('employees','employees.id','=','employee_exams.employee_id')
                    ->join('exams', 'exams.id', '=', 'employee_exams.exam_id')
                    ->when($data_inicio, function ($query) use ($data_inicio) {
                        return $query->where('next_exam', '>=', $data_inicio);
                    })
                    ->when($data_final, function ($query) use ($data_final) {
                        return $query->where('next_exam', '<=', $data_final);
                    })  
                    ->orderBy('employee_exams.next_exam', 'asc')
                    ->get(['employee_exams.*',
                           'employees.id', 
                           'employees.identidade', 
                           'exams.exame']
                     );
```

Sucesso!